# angular nested routing parent to child variables

Tags: angular

I have this route:

```
{ 
  path: ':parent_id',
  component: Parent, 
  children: [
    {
      path: 'child',
      children: [
        {
          path: ':child_id',
          component: Child
         }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I retrieve the parent_id value from within the Child component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to access it using the `ActivatedRoute`

First import it: `import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";`

Then try something like this:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {

  this.route.parent.params.subscribe((params) => {
    console.log(params); // This would show you all the available params

    if (params['parent_id']) { 
      console.log(params['term']) // Prints the console parent_id param
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: I have this in ngOnInit:
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((p: ParamMap) => {
        const parent_id = p.get('parent_id');
        ...

but it is null.

Comment: Try using `this.route.parent.params` instead of `this.route.params`

Comment: nice. I just noticed that ActivatedRoute had a parent property. Thanks.
this.route.parent.paramMap.subscribe((p: ParamMap) => { console.log(p.get('parent_id')); });

Comment: Nice, I updated my answer to say `route.parent.params`